# How drag force relates to velocity in the air?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, viscosity

As you know in the formula of drag $$F=0.5 *d*A*C*v^2$$ in different velocities we have different Reynolds number. and the Reynolds number relates to coefficient of drag. my question is how can we calculate the drag force as a function of velocity?

Answer (score 2):

if objects have a blunt form factor and the fluid have a large enough Reynolds number in order to produce turbulence behind the object. The equation is

[image]

where, the drag force =  mass density * flow velocity relative to the object * reference area *  drag coefficient

and we know,

[image]

[image]

so, you should write all the drag coefficient and Reynolds number as function of velocity and then write them in the main equation.

in this equation we can see how the drag force is propoional with velocity.